# how to get all the arguments in a command captured in a windows .bat file

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, command-line-arguments

```
grep -P  "ERROR.+SQLTransientConnectionException" uts.log  | wc -l
```

I was trying to copy/capture the above (previous) command to the clipboard.
My attempt was a batch file ec.bat with below contents

```
echo %* | clip
```

However, when I tried that on the previously run command like below

```
ec.bat grep -P  "ERROR.+SQLTransientConnectionException" uts.log  | wc -l
```

it only copied the grep part(like below) not the entire command line. It left out the pipe(|) and the "wc -l"

```
grep -P  "ERROR.+SQLTransientConnectionException" uts.log
```

How can I get/request the entire command line ? Is there an environment variable containing the previous command ? Is there something similar to the bash/zsh special parameters like explained [here](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_05_02)

Comment: Would `@(Echo=%CmdCmdLine%)|Clip` be satisfactory?

Comment: The pipe (`|`) is not an argument of the batch file, hence `%*` does not reflect it, and neither does `CmdCmdLine`. Since either part of a pipe is executed inside a new `cmd` child instance, I think it is not possible for a batch file involved in the pipe to "see" the whole command line that is executed in the parent `cmd` instance…

Comment: What about a different approach, relying on the assumption that there is only one instance of the batch script running: check the command lines of running processes and search them for `ec.bat` and `|`?

Comment: @aschipfl : Thank you. That assumption holds good for now. I will try your alternate approach but I thought cmd.exe would have something like the bash and other shells for this use-case.

Comment: for others looking for a solution, I could have passed a quote after ec.bat and close the quote at the end of the command line. remove these quotes in the ec.bat and then copied the full command to clipboard. But the holy grail is to get at the full command without adding the quotes -- so, I'll try what @aschipfl suggested.

Comment: Well, if the pipe symbol `|` appears in between quotes, it no longer constitutes a functional pipe but just as a literal character, but that is not what you want, is it?

Comment: @aschipfl : I work in the command line. Sometimes, the command I have worked out in the cmd.exe is good to put into a shell script. that's when I want to copy the entire command to the clipboard so that I can put it into a shell script edited in an editor or using the ec.bat script to automatically create a new shell script. The assumption is that the quotes will be removed in the editor or the ec.bat shell script will save it into a new shell script after removing the quotes, of course!

Comment: @aschipfl, "relying on the assumption that there is only one instance of the batch script running: check the command lines of running processes and search them for ec.bat an" -- I tried this approach but unforunately, cmd.exe doesn't spawn a new cmd.exe with the new command line including ec.bat. So, I cant' do a ps(or pslist) to grab the command line from ps(or pslist).

Comment: so, the solution was to get at the history of the command prompt and then pull the last command!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this problem from another angle. I tried to find the history of the command prompt.

From [https://www.itechtics.com/view-command-prompt-history-windows/#:~:text=Open%20CMD%20from%20the%20Start,within%20the%20window%20of%20CMD.](https://www.itechtics.com/view-command-prompt-history-windows/#:%7E:text=Open%20CMD%20from%20the%20Start,within%20the%20window%20of%20CMD.), I found that you can type a command "doskey /history" which gives the history. I can use tail to grab the previous command and work on it as required.

I guess it helps to work on a problem from different angles.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a doskey macro.

`doskey ec=toclip.bat "$*"`

And in the batch file `toclip.bat`

```
@echo off
set line=%*
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
REM *** Remove the surrounding quotes from line
for /F "delims=" %%L in ("!line!") DO (
    endlocal
    (echo(%%~L) | clip
)
```

It's unexpected, but doskey macros have precendence over normal cmd.exe parsing.
That results into quotes around your arguments.

But it fails, if your arguments contain quotes itself, like

```
ec grep "hello|world" file
```